# PiCam shoots blank images

Tags: raspicam

Raspberry PiCam is showing blank white images on Raspbian Buster. The raspberry PiCam was working with Jessie. I tried `raspistill -o test.jpg` and got a blank white square in `test.jpg`.

https://drive.google.com/file/d/16jX8nZKGYngVt7yNoyPDUwx03gL1QMKD/view?usp=sharing
https://drive.google.com/file/d/16_lQkLHDsCsR1mscDdu5ZF5SeMEVm_Ym/view?usp=sharing

Color of the square changes based on programs I use to take the picture
for example in `picamera`(Python) it takes black squares, in `raspistill` it takes white squares.

Comment: Can you post a picture of your wiring?

Comment: added plz check

Comment: Did you remember to re-enable the camera in raspi-config (or the GUI equivalent) when you made the Buster install?

Comment: @Andyroo yes, enabled, rebooted and disabled to check if enabling really happened. When enabled it gives the white square as image, when disabled it gives error message saying unable to detect camera.

Answer (score 0):

This post: [Common errors using the Raspberry Pi camera module](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2016/08/29/common-errors-using-the-raspberry-pi-camera-module/) suggests at least two possible solutions:

- `sudo rpi-update` to update Raspberry firmware
- downgrade the picamera package

Comment: did `rpi-update`. Both picamera and rpstill are(were) malfunctioning identically so i don't know why updating or downgrading picamera(which is just a python interface) will be help.

Comment: You did reboot right ? Have you tried `raspistill` and `raspivid` ?

Comment: yes both, `raspistill` and `raspivid` both successfully record blank white squares.